# How to add backslash into perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to figure out how to have backslashes in my perl that will show up along with my words. 
When I perl my file the backslash is not there.

Here is what I have:

```
print "Olive Garden \ Lina's\n";
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Olive Garden \ Lina's
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\` has a special meaning in double-quote string literals. As you know, `\n` resulting in a line feed is an example of this. You can use `\\` to produce a backslash.

```
print "Olive Garden \\ Lina's\n";
```

See [Quote and Quote-like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for more details.